# Python: Plot frequency of negative (x,y) coordinates

Tags: python, matplotlib, colorbar, imshow, random-walk

I'm trying to plot the frequencies of a 2D-integer random walk starting from (0,0). First, I get a list of (x,y)-coordinates, some of which are negative and I'm having problems plotting them the right way. I know my current attempt is wrong, as (0,0) sometimes look like its not in the random walk at all.

Here's my attempt:

The idea is to transpose all (x,y)-coordinates, so they're in the first quadrant and then manipulate the axes on `extent` to transpose them back to their original form. I do so in order to avoid unwanted list-operations in the construction of `grid`, which would make the plot 'jump'

```
# generate random walk
import random

def random_walk():

    a = 0
    b = 0
    while True:
        yield (a, b)

        i = random.choice([0, 1])
        if i == 0:
            a = random.choice([a-1, a+1])
        else:
            b = random.choice([b-1, b+1])
```

And the attempt at plotting itself:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import itertools 
import numpy as np

# generate random walk of length 1000
walk = list(itertools.islice(random_walk(), 0, 1000))

xy = list(zip(*walk))

x = list(xy[0])
y = list(xy[1])

ext = (min(x), max(x), min(y), max(y))

min_x = min(x)
min_y = min(y)

# transpose all x.- and y.-coordinates:

for i in range(len(x)):
    x[i] -= min_x

for i in range(len(y)):
    y[i] -= min_y

walk_new = list(zip(x,y))

grid = np.zeros((max(x) + 1, max(y) + 1))

# Put frequencies in grid:
for a,b in walk_new:
    grid[a][b] += 1


plt.imshow(grid)
plt.colorbar()
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I did notice that the origin (0,0) didn't show up on your heatmap as expected when I ran your code. I left your random_walk function as is, but I think using matplotlib's hist2d would be easier here, as the (x,y) coordinates display exactly as you like with no need for transposing the coordinates you generated.

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import itertools 
import numpy as np

# generate random walk of length 1000
walk = list(itertools.islice(random_walk(), 0, 1000))

xy = list(zip(*walk))

x = list(xy[0])
y = list(xy[1])

heatmap, xedges, yedges = np.histogram2d(x, y, bins=[np.arange(min(x),max(x),1),np.arange(min(y),max(y),1)])
extent = [xedges[0], xedges[-1], yedges[0], yedges[-1]]
plt.imshow(heatmap, origin='lower', extent=extent)

# set bins to be 1 unit apart since your (x,y) coordinates are integers
# plt.hist2d(x,y, bins=[np.arange(min(x),max(x),1),np.arange(min(y),max(y),1)])
plt.colorbar()
plt.show()
```

[image]

Comment: Cheers. Do you know how to do this with imshow()? I'm trying to reuse the same functions in the overall document of which this is a part.

Comment: Hi I'll give it go!